# Custom CQWP itemstyle with link to library

Tags: content-query-web-part, hyperlink, item-styles

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow create a new itemstyle which has a link to the library where the items in the content query is located?

Example:

1. First ListItem
2. Second ListItem
3. Third ListItem
4. Fourth ListItem
5. Fifth ListItem

View all items *<-- this being the link to the library*

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the anchor tag with a dynamic link to the bottom of your itemstyle xsl and then wrap it with an xsl:if statement to check the position to see if the last list item is last.

```
<xsl:if test="position() =last()">
   <a href="link.aspx">View all items</a>
</xsl:if>
```

If you want to make the href dynamic, find a source for the link in your XML somewhere and use:

```
<a href="{@source}">View all items</a>
```

You may have to use XSL to remove formatting after a certain character to achieve the path to the libary from another link

Comment: It doesn't work - position() is always the same (1) for all returned items. I put the snippet in the end of my ItemStyle.xsl template.

Comment: Had to use this method to get it to work http://blog.mastykarz.nl/alternative-display-order-content-query-web-part/